# Async await or .then() are returning undefined for redux actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dispatch

I'm doing this: `await dispatch(myfunction(arg1))` and if I add `.then()` or

```
const x = await dispatch(myfunction(arg1)) 
console.log(x)
```

both come back as undefined...

but when I view the response in the browser I get back the data I'm expecting

any ideas?

the action creator just goes through some middleware and calls some actions, no idea why it's undefined though

Comment: `dispatch` won't return you anything, it will just go and update the redux store which then will be reflected in the component which subscribes to this store.

Comment: Why do you need to await on this sample? Maybe, we need more information about what you want to do

Comment: well I need the updated state afterwards to perform something based upon it...but when I log `getState().myObject` it's returning `{}` but it should be populated like it is in the response in the browser :/

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I thought `dispatch` was synchronous so why am I getting the incorrect state when I call `getState()` after dispatch?

Comment: You should Middleware or thunk to perform network calls. That will let you await them as well

Answer (score 3):

Dispatch does not return a promise. It simply triggers an update to occur.
If you need to use promises, look into using redux-thunk, then do something like:

```js
let thunkAction = async (args1) => {
   let res = await myFunction(args1);
   dispatch(someUpdate(res));
}
```

Comment: I am using redux thunk. so do I need to change my action creator?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `redux-thunk` module to your project. This module permit to concatenate dispatching actions by returning a promise if you return the `dispatch` function from your action, like:

```js
// I normally use action creator
const myAction = (args) => dispatch => {
return dispatch({ type: 'MY_ACTION', payload: args });
}
```

So you can concatenate:

```js
const applyActions = () => {
myAction('test').then(() => {});
}
```